# Deepin White screen

Tags: linux, arch-linux, lightdm, deepin, lightdm-gtk-greeter

I installed deepin on Arch (fresh install) and it just isn't working, I can't log in, when I start the lightdm.service, it just shows blank white screen. I haven't enable the service yet. I was just checking if it worked and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

There might be an issue with the lightdm-deepin-greeter.

Install an alternative greeter, e.g lightdm-gtk-greeter

```
sudo pacman -S lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Then edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

```
sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Look for the line that is like 
`greeter-session=lightdm-deepin-greeter` or the value could be something else
change it to

```
greeter-session=lightdm-gtk-greeter
```

Save, `ctrl-x, y, [enter]`

Stop & start the lightdm.service and see if that works.

```
systemctl stop lightdm
systemctl start lightdm
```

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've ran into the same issue as you

Turn out I have not create a non root user, fixed by:

```
useradd -m newuser
passwd newuser
systemctl restart lightdm
```

then the beautiful Deepin login screen is appear! Hope you fixed it